how to change specific days background color in fullcalendar using React JS
I am using fullcalendar in my React JS application for employee attendance project. I have to change background color of that day when employee would be on leave.
I am getting employee attendance details in List from API.
const newEvents = events?.map((event) => ({
id: event?.emp_id,
    title: event?.attendance_val,
    start: event?.att_date,
    display:  "background",
    allDay: true,
  }));

console.log("new events =>", newEvents);

I printed this new Events list in console am getting all data about the selected employees.

Now i have to change that day color when title is 'Leave'.
I am using
eventBackgroundColor= {newEvents ? "#ff0000" : "#919eab4d"} 

but only last value day (29th Feb)'s color is changing.
I also tried
eventBackgroundColor= {newEvents.title === "Leave" ? "#ff0000" : "#919eab4d"} 

but it's throwing an error.

React code is as below
    <Card>
      <StyledCalendar>
        <CalendarToolbar
          date={date}
          view={view}
          // loading={eventsLoading}
          onNextDate={onDateNext}
          onPrevDate={onDatePrev}
          onToday={onDateToday}
          onChangeView={onChangeView}
          onOpenFilters={openFilters.onTrue}
        />

        <Calendar
          weekends
          editable
          droppable
          selectable
          rerenderDelay={10}
          allDayMaintainDuration
          eventResizableFromStart
          ref={calendarRef}
          initialDate={date}
          initialView={view}
          dayMaxEventRows={3}
          eventDisplay="block"
          events={newEvents}
          // eventBackgroundColor= {newEvents.title === "Leave" ? "#ff0000" : "#919eab4d"}
          eventBackgroundColor= {newEvents ? "#ff0000" : "#919eab4d"}
          headerToolbar={false}
          select={onSelectRange}
          height={smUp ? 720 : 'auto'}
          plugins={[
            listPlugin,
            dayGridPlugin,
            timelinePlugin,
            timeGridPlugin,
            interactionPlugin,
          ]}
        />
      </StyledCalendar>
    </Card>


You can't use eventBackgroundColor to set colours for individual events. As per the documentation this option only accepts a simple string containing a colour value. It doesn't accept callbacks etc.
It does also mention though that:

This option can be overridden on a per-source basis with the backgroundColor Event Source Object option or on a per-event basis with the backgroundColor Event Object option.

So that's the route you need to go down, most likely.
You can either set the event's backgroundColor property when you're generating the event feed, or if that's not possible you could use the eventDataTransform callback  to run the colour-choosing logic on each event as it is imported into the calendar.
Here's an example with the colour pre-loaded into a JSON event object, ready for passing to fullCalendar:
{
  "title": "Leave",
  "start": "2024-04-11",
  "end": "2024-04-13",
  "display": "background",
  "backgroundColor": "#ff0000",
  "allDay": true
}

In your case you could also achieve it like this when you're mapping your events from the API into fullCalendar format:
const newEvents = events?.map((event) => ({
id: event?.emp_id,
    title: event?.attendance_val,
    start: event?.att_date,
    display:  "background",
    backgroundColor: (event?.attendance_val === "Leave" ? "#ff0000" : "#919eab4d");
    allDay: true,
  }));

Alternatively here's an example of the approach using eventDataTransform:
eventDataTransform = {handleEventDataTransform}

...

function handleEventDataTransform(eventData) {
  eventData.backgroundColor = (eventData.title === "Leave" ? "#ff0000" : "#919eab4d");
  return eventData;
}

